# -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString _UIKBStringWideAttributeValueForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x11ba0740

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitextfield, nsmutableattributedstring

I have an app where app is getting crashed when I click on textfield in iOS6. The crash occurs saying below message.

```
-[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString _UIKBStringWideAttributeValueForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x11ba0740
```

I have an app with English and Arabic version. For arabic, I am using `NSMutableAttributedString` and set text as `textField.attributedText`

**It works fine with iOS 7. Problem is with iOS 6 only.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the problem, but below is how I solved.

in `viewDidLoad` I added below.

```
[fullName addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchValueChangedUN) forControlEvents: UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
```

Then used `handleTouchValueChangedUN` as below.

```
-(void) handleTouchValueChangedUN {
    [User_FullName setString:fullName.text];
}
```

Added`textFieldShouldBeginEditing` where I set text as blank and then set its value to its actual value.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    textField.text = @"";
    if (textField==fullName) {
        attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:User_FullName attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:localize(@"myFontName") size:[localize(@"fontSize001") floatValue]], NSLigatureAttributeName: @2}];
        textField.attributedText = attributedString;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

***However I am more concerned for this as this never happened to me before. This is first time I am experiencing.***